# I can plot a histogram from a CVS file, but I can't do it for a specific column. Can anyone provide advice?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a histogram from a cvs file/excel spread sheet I extracted locally. I can plot the histogram for all the columns, but I want to do it only for one column. Same thing for using describe for stats. I can't seem to find a tutorial that covers this. Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
def House_Data():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\CsvPractice\Housing.csv', names=['AGE','BEDRMS','BUILT','NUNITS','ROOMS','WEIGHT','UTILITY'])
    dp = pd.read_csv(r'C:\CsvPractice\Housing.csv')
    histogram = dp.hist()
    
    print(dp.describe())
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Does my answer below not do what you want? If I have misunderstood your question, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can access individual columns as, e.g., `df['AGE']`. For example,

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5,6,6,6,7,9], 'B' : [4,5,1,6,6,7,7]})
df['A'].hist()
df['A'].describe()
```

just plots the histogram and data summary for column 'A'.